# Block Crawlers on Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, apache-1.3

I am trying to block crawlers on Apache

```
    <Directory /to/my/site/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order deny,allow
        deny from 18.*.*.*
        deny from 35.*.*.*
        deny from *.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
        deny from *.*.compute.amazonaws.com
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

However this does not seem to block traffic coming from any of these IPs. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should try to add a [robots.txt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard) to your web page to stop polite crawlers.

Your `Deny` statements do not work, since you use a not supported syntax for wildcard (cf. [Apache's documentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard)). The directives should be:

```
Deny from 18 35
Deny from .compute.amazonaws.com
```